# Cannot get the cuda printf result in wsl2

Tags: cuda, wsl-2

The code (main.cu) is:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

__global__ void kernel() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}

int main() {
    kernel<<<1, 1>>>();
    
    {
    cudaError_t cudaerr = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaerr != cudaSuccess)
        printf("kernel launch failed with error \"%s\".\n",
               cudaGetErrorString(cudaerr));
    else
        printf("cudaerr == cudaSuccess\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I use cmake version 3.27.5, and the CMakeLists.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

project(hellocuda LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

add_executable(main main.cu)
```

The build result is

```
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/me/project/cuda_hello/build
[ 50%] Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cu.o
[100%] Linking CUDA executable main
[100%] Built target main
cudaerr == cudaSuccess
```

There is no "Hello, world!\n" result in terminal, I can't see the print output of cuda kernel() function.

How can I get the cuda printf result?

used `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` in the main() func, but still not working.

`nvcc --verison`

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_15_22:02:13_PDT_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.2, V12.2.140
Build cuda_12.2.r12.2/compiler.33191640_0
```

`which nvcc`

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc
```

`wsl -l -v`

```
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* ubuntu    Running         2
```

the distribution is ubuntu 20.04 in wsl2.

Comment: What happens if you run the executable from a command line shell and not from within the CMake build?

Comment: thanks, only output from cpu: cudaerr == cudaSuccess

Comment: So in other words, the kernel is never running. Check the kernel launch status like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14038590/681865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was solved after adding

```
set_target_properties(main PROPERTIES CUDA_ARCHITECTURES "72;80")
```

in CMakeLists.txt